# Mysql create table from csv

Tags: mysql, csv

In order to create a table from csv file , i have followed that link [Import CSV File Into MySQL Table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)
I create the table structure , the problem that its values doesn't match with the csv file values for each row.
what may be the problem ?

the table structure is :

> CREATE TABLE `products` (
>
> `id_p` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `nom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `ref` int(11) NOT NULL,
>    `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
>
> `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `shopname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `id_shop_default` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `id_image` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `name_category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `price_final` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `is_virtual` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `downla` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `sav_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `badge_danger` int(11) NOT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

and the csv structure is :

[image: part1]
[image: part2of csv]

the rasult in the database was :
[image]

below are the 10 first rows from the csv when editing by text editor ( may the ,; for exemple in ligne 1 the problem?

```html
id_product;name;reference;price;active;shopname;id_shop_default;id_image;name_category;price_final;is_virtual;nb_downloadable;sav_quantity;badge_danger
1;CORRECTEUR DE PROJECTEUR NEUF... CITROEN PEUGEOT ;14.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;1; Ampoule,Platine et divers,;0;0 ;1;0
2;ECLAIRAGE DE PLAQUE AR SEIMA 856...PEUGEOT 204 ;29.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;2; Feu,Cabochon int/ext divers,;0;0 ;1;0
3;RACCORD D'EAU METAL 4 SORTIES...POUR PEUGEOT CITROEN RENAULT SIMCA ;7.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;3; Bocal, Pompe lave glace,;0;0 ;1;0
4;REFRIGERATEUR DE CIRCUIT D'HUILE...CITROEN 2CV AZAM ;69.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;4; Radiateurs,Bouchons,Joints,;0;0 ;1;0
5;VERRE DE FEU AR CLIGNOTANT...DS HY GS BX 104 204 304 504 R4 R5 R8 R10 R12... ;12.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;5; Feu,Cabochon int/ext divers,;0;0 ;1;0
6;ETRIER DE FREIN AVANT GAUCHE  BENDIX...RENAULT R18 ;59.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;6; Disque,Etrier,Tambour;0;0 ;1;0
7;PARE CHOC ARRIERE COTE GAUCHE...PEUGEOT SIMCA CITROEN RENAULT ;39.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;7; Parechoc, Butoirs, Butées;0;0 ;1;0
8;T DE RACCORD DE LAVE GLACE...POUR PEUGEOT CITROEN RENAULT SIMCA ;6.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;8; Bocal, Pompe lave glace,;0;0 ;4;0
9;JOINT METALLO ...RENAULT PEUGEOT CITROEN SIMCA PANHARD ;9.750000;1;Tracauto1950;1;9; Joint,Silentbloc,Accessoires;0;0 ;1;0
```

)

Comment: It would help if you showed us the SQL that creates your table, then a portion of the CSV file and the stored values in the database. Tell us where you think there is a mismatch. Then perhaps we can find the reason.

Comment: i have updated the post by adding table strcuture and the csv file strcuture : it is devided into two parts

Comment: Can you provide the `LOAD DATA INFILE...` command you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to load the CSV in the tutorial is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I've noticed that your fields are not enclosed by any quotes, so you should have changed the load command to something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/dir/dir/your_file.csv' 
INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY ''  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The major change is this bit: `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY ''` And you cannot use `;` inside any field. Of course you should have read this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html